# How can I make Firefox display favicons in the address bar?

Tags: firefox, browser, favicon

Firefox 14 [drops the icon from its address bar](http://iloveubuntu.net/firefox-14-nightly-received-enhanced-favicon-behavior) - what is a good way of getting it back?
I fully understand the security concerns, but I am missing the icon - having it in the tab only isn't the same.
I would prefer an about:config entry, if such exist, but I will settle for a small extension.

Comment: On a personal note: usually I embrace all UI changes - no point in going against them, but not this one... First, I like them icons. Second, I am missing some features, like the Google's mail count, or calendar date - the change make these websites a little less usable, in my opinion...

Comment: Please note that this question is **not** about ubuntu, or any specific OS. I just chose a link with ubuntu screenshot.

Comment: [The official announcement](https://blog.mozilla.org/ux/2012/06/site-identity-ui-updates/) (?), linked from the [Firefox 14 release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/14.0.1/releasenotes/).

Comment: But change makes sense, before you would see favicon double on the tab itself and next to url... this doubling had no advantage for user. Try it out for few days, you are going to get used to it :) What you are experiencing is normal, happens to all kinds of UI changes, look how much people complain when facebook changes graphics etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try **[Favicon Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/favicon-restorer/)** addon which brings the website favicons back into the Location Bar in Firefox 14 and later.

Comment: Not bad! It does have some minor issues (like a small delay when changing tabs), but it shows both the favicon and a lock icon, which is very nice. I'll use it for a while, see how it goes, and I'll come back to accept this answer when I'm happy `:)` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've created a patch for the `omni.ja` file that uses the old code and style. You can check [here](http://lilydjwg.is-programmer.com/2012/7/29/revert-new-site-identity-feature-and-show-favicon-in-urlbar-for-firefox-14.34782.html) for the patch and a patched `omni.ja` file.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Custom Buttons add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-buttons/) first and then install the [Urlbar Favicon Inserter Button](http://custombuttons.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=344). Next you only need to customize your toolbar and drag the new button to your toolbar and you're done: the favicon is back. Right now, this is the only solution to get the favicon back into the urlbar that I know of.

If you feel the need to modify your Site Identity Button colors, you may want to check out yet another extension: [Site Identity Button Colors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/site-identity-button-colors/).